# I,m trying to put graph on webpage from mysql database I'm getting one error $ is not defined How can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to put Graph on my webpage which will show temp of patient according to there patient_id when some 1 select it from select tag but i'm getting this issue in my graph page that $ is not defined in (line 2) error.
what do i need to do solve these issue ?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
  /**
   * call the data.php file to fetch the result from db table.
   */
  $.ajax({
    url : "/followdata_temp.php",  //in followdata_temp.php data is declared.
    type : "GET",
    success : function(data){
      console.log(data);
      var time = [];
      var temp = [];
      var len = data.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
               time.push("" + data[i].time);
        temp.push(data[i].temp);
      }
      //get canvas
      var ctx = $("#line-chartcanvas");   
      var chartdata = {
        labels : time,
        datasets : [
          { 
         label : "Temperature",
            data : temp,
            backgroundColor : "blue",
            borderColor : "lightblue",
            fill : false,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointRadius : 5
          }
        ]
      };
      var chart = new Chart( ctx, {
        type : "line",
        data : chartdata
       });
},
    error : function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
    </script>
```

It should plot graph in my acctual page

Comment: Import jQuery: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you!!!! now graph is showing but data is not plotting on it even if i fetch the data from phpmyadmin(database) from page "/followdata_temp" it's printing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have To Import jQuery First Just Put This line before your script tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! i have put import jQuery now graph is showing but data is not plotting on it even if i fetch the data from phpmyadmin(database) from page "/followdata_temp" it's printing data